# DreamHost CGI result seen as text

Tags: cgi

I am testing a CGI that locally is working fine as HTML, but when executed from DreamHost it shows as text:

http://www.fivetechsoft.net/cgi-bin/tutor01.cgi

If executed locally it shows fine:

localhost/cgi-bin/tutor01.cgi

Any hints why it is not seen as HTML from DreamHost ? Content-Type is properly set as "Content-Type: text/html", thanks

Antonio

Comment: example: #include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
   printf( "Content-Type: text/html\n\n" );
   printf( "<h1>Hello world</h1>" );
   return 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Apache is sending some bogus headers, seems to be ANSI escape codes. Which means your Content-Type line is not valid, and Apache replaces it with its default Content-Type.

```
$ curl -si http://www.fivetechsoft.net/cgi-bin/tutor01.cgi | less
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 27 Oct 2012 20:31:38 GMT
Server: Apache
ESC[0mESC[1;1HESC[?25hESC[0;10;37;40mESC[mContent-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain

<html>
<head>
...
```